# Why my ListView does not accept my custom OnItemSelectedListener?

Tags: android, listener

I have a ListView,
I want to create an OnItemSelectedListner, which I do in the code, and i call it mylistener.
Why the list.setOnItemSelectedListener does not accept mylistener?

Thank for the help

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);   
        list.setOnItemSelectedListener(mlistener);
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mlistener = new     AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"selezionato",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        };
```

Comment: Declare `mlistener` **before** setting it on the `ListView`.

Comment: Eclipse warns "mlistener cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: @Luksprog thanks, I thought I did it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare and initialize `mlistener` before using it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create the listener before `list.setOnItemSelectedListener(mlistener);`

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder your code:

```
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,array);
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener mlistener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"selezionato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};

list.setAdapter(adapter);   
list.setOnItemSelectedListener(mlistener);
```